# Retrieving user profile properties in Application Customizer (SharePoint Framework)

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I'm currently working with the SharePoint Framework Extensions that are currently in developer preview – specifically Application Customizers. How can I lookup user profile properties for the current user?

Comment: What properties do you want ? Can you tell us ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PnP JS to get the entire user profile properties as shown below :

```
pnp.sp.profiles.myProperties.get().then(function(result) {
var userProperties = result.UserProfileProperties;
var userPropertyValues = "";
userProperties.forEach(function(property) {
userPropertyValues += property.Key + " - " + property.Value + "<br/>";
});
document.getElementById("spUserProfileProperties").innerHTML = userPropertyValues;
}).catch(function(error) {
 console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

[get User Profile properties using SPFx and PnP JS](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/SharePoint-Framework-Development-Create-UserProfile-webPart-PnPJS.html)

[image]

Comment: this can be used in webpart, but not in application customizer